# Got late order email in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, email

I have got very late order-related mail for some customer what can I do any have an idea for same?
I have checked with the same email address with custom PHP mail function then it will working but when the order place customer get late mail after 30 minute

I have noticed,  Mail received properly for Indian customer but UK customer get late mail

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Any solution did you get yet? i also face the same issue

Comment: Hello, Pratik we have configured SMTP and it has been working for me. try SMTP configure with India Gmail first then try with client Gmail as well

Answer (score 0):

Please disable Asynchronous sending
From

> Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails

[image]